# Service doesn't work when moved from original folder

Tags: c#, windows, service, tcp, tcpclient

So I had a running code for a windows service in C#, the .exe file was run as a service and was working fine. I wanted to move the .exe somehwhere else, and run the service from the new location, but it doesn't accept any connections. After some debugging i reached the stopping point.

```
            try
            {
                client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Mailer.ReportUpdate("bla.bla@bla.com", "Exception", e.Message);
```

I dont recieve an email about any exceptions, yet no connections are accepted. I also checked and the port is in use, which means it should be listening. I can't figure out why does it work as a program and not as a service, and why works as a service in the original location of the project of VS(Debug folder) and not when i move it away.

Comment: I think this has to do with the location of the .exe file the service is running, and it runs fine as a program, so I dont think it would be blocked as a service, its the same firewall rule I believe

Comment: When you say running as a service, do you mean you've compiled it and installed it as a service (i.e. it appears in the View Local Services snap-in)?

Comment: A firewall rule can be tied to an executable location. _"I don't think"_ isn't going to give a definitive answer, so: check your firewall. Your service runs, it doesn't give an error, yet you can't connect to it: 9 out of 10 times it's the firewall.

Comment: @CodeCaster You were right dude! I had a firewall rule for the old/original location, but not the new one. Totally forgot about doing a new rule for the new location! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as @CodeCaster said in the comments, It was a firewall issue. I had to create a new rule for the new location.